# Play mp4 files in python

Tags: python, pygame, mp4

I have 2 mp4 clips I would like to play in a window with Python.
I want the first clip to be played and then at some point to switch to the second clip in the middle of the first one (when a function is called).

It supposed to look like this

```
play_first_clip():
   pass

play_second_clip():
   pass
```

For example when the first clip is played and then `play_second_clip()` is called, the window will switch to the second clip even if the first one is not done yet.

I tried to do that with `Pymovie`

```
first = VideoFileClip('first')
first.preview()
second = VideoFileClip('second')
second.preview()
```

But this of course will play the second video after the first one is finished.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Just so im understanding the question correctly - You have `clip1` that will be playing (say its background music or something) and then on some event `clip2` should stop `clip1` and play `clip2`'s sound? Is this sounding correct?

Comment: You should run two instances of any mp4 player application in parallel.  The two should be remotely controllable (e. g. via stdin).  On a Raspberry Pi I just did this using the omxplayer which is the standard there.  Then you can send PAUSE to the one and PLAY to the other whenever you like.  Have a look at the subprocess module used to run child processes.

Comment: Yes this is correct

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use openCV and show the videos frame by frame, in that way you can control the next frame and interrupt a video at any time

```
def start_main_loop(self):
    while 1:
        ret, frame = self.current_state.read()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            self.close()
            break
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('Game', frame)
```